# No 'start rollout to internal testing' button while creating internal testing release in google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

Recently I have faced an issue during the creation of internal testing release in play console. Usually the workflow is that you 'Create new release', upload your bundle, click next and there should be 'Start rollout to internal testing' button. But for some reason last time we attempted to create an internal testing release we found that this button is missing, but there is 'Save and publish', also on the left there is text: 'Changes made will be published to Google Plav immediatelv'.

With that in mind I am nervous that maybe something is wrong and this release will go directly to production, without being available for internal testing first.

Can you please help me find the reason?

I've read many google articles and went through multiple guides, but they either are short on details or have no screenshots to check if everything is right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Internal testing" is not "Production", hence this release will only be made available to the testers configured in the internal testing track.

Edit:
The button has just been renamed, this doesn't change anything to the outcome. "Rollout" implied "publishing".

The reason it says "Changes made will be published to Google Play immediately" is to highlight the fact that no review is required for changes in the internal testing track, the update will be made available *to the testers* immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand the difference between 'internal testing' and 'production', though I am confused because it used be different (I mean the set of buttons). Like on this video (and similar ones): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkq8T2gvvRg you can see (after 1:40) that after creating a release and uploading it button 'Start rollout to internal testing' appears, on the other hand I have different result, I see only 'Save and publish' and it really confuses me.

Comment: You are correct, it seems that the behaviour changed, let me investigate more and get back to you.

Comment: I've updated my answer, PTAL. The name of the button has been changed, the behaviour has not.

Comment: I see, can you please share links, where you have found information about button changes?

Comment: I work at Google and have asked relevant people.

Comment: @Pierre thanks! can you tell them to revert back this confusing change plz?

Comment: Change can be difficult :) There is a feedback component in the Play Console where you can share your feedback directly with the team